# Codeigniter routing to an href id

Tags: codeigniter, url, hyperlink

I've made a one-page design and would like to route somesite.com/contact to somesite.com/index.php#contact. I'm using a href id's and div id's. But none of the routes i make seems to be working.

examples:

- $route['contact'] = "pagescontroller/index#contact";
- $route['contact'] = "base_url('#contact')";

How could i make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: htaccess my friend, htaccess...

Comment: My skills in htacces are very limited, i can't use CI routes for this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `#` so the browser knows you are going to a part of the page.  If you really want to remove it, you could use it as a parameter for the controllermethod you use to display your page and use javascript to go the that specific id on your page.
I would not do that since you will reload your page every time you click on a link. (Unless you use javascript to suppress that as well and go to the relevant ID.)

You could however use mod_rewrite in .htaccess for removing the index.php from your url.  So your url's will look like http://example.com/#about

My .htaccess-file for codeigniter is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Wait, i've put an contactform on this page, i would see an message when its sends, the message is there alright, but the contact page is at the bottom, with a refresh the page is at its top. That's why i'd like to cover the index.php#contact url to /contact so i could return to the exact page.

Comment: You could return to http://example.com/#contact, so you will go to the right height.  Otherwise you will have to use some javascript to go to the right height.  You could also process your form at http://example.com/contact, store your message in session-flash-data, redirect to http://example.com/#contact and show your message.

Comment: Maybe you could use ajax to send your form and show the message, this way you'll also stay at the right height.